# Formal definition of a pretzel link

Tags: knot-theory

All the definitions of a pretzel link $P(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ I've seen so far are defined using the knot diagram, in a very informal way. Could anyone give me a **formal definition** for a pretzel link?

Comment: Diagrammatic definitions are formal definitions.  Perhaps you are looking for a geometric or topological characterization of pretzel knots?

Comment: @N.Owad Yes, I'm looking for a topological (or even geometric) definition.